# One-to-one relationship modelBuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to set a one-to-one relationship. Where do I write these lines, please?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Instructor) 
    .WithOptional(t => t.OfficeAssignment);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can either define it as you have above, or you can do it in your models using conventions.  Does the above not create your relationship?

Comment: @Johan, do I write it in the strong class?

Comment: You write that line of code in the OnModelCraeting method (which you can override in the context class), see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You will write those lines of code in your context class, in the OnModelCreating method

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<OfficeAssignment> OfficeAssignments { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>() 
                        .HasRequired(t => t.Instructor) 
                        .WithOptional(t => t.OfficeAssignment);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in the context class e.g:

```
   public class AssignmentContext : DbContext
   {
      public IDbSet<OfficeAssignment> OfficeAssignments { get; set; }
      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>() 
             .HasRequired(t => t.Instructor) 
             .WithOptional(t => t.OfficeAssignment);
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      }
   }
```